# Is it possible to use Neo4j as a library?

Tags: neo4j

I'm working on a Java game project that would benefit a lot from the graph traversal algorithms and query languages included in Neo4j. Unfortunately, querying a server takes too much time and I would like to know if it's possible to use Neo4J as a library, with queries happening in-memory?

Comment: Hi vinnylinux. I have updated my answer with an alternative solution, please take a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can embed Neo4j in Java applications. Take a look in the [docs](https://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/current/tutorials-java-embedded/). If you are working in a Maven project, you can add Neo4j as a Maven dependency:

```
<project>
...
 <dependencies>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
   <artifactId>neo4j</artifactId>
   <version>3.3.2</version>
  </dependency>
  ...
 </dependencies>
...
</project>
```

Also, there is an [ImpermanentDataBase](https://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/3.3/tutorials-java-embedded/#tutorials-java-unit-testing) developed for unit test purposes.